# Excel TEXTJOIN and FILTERXML wrong string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a table and I want to filter data  by date and ID and join text from corresponding columns. But I still missing the last text string. It should be " text5 - text6 - text5" instead of "text5 - text6". I use following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<k><m>"&TEXTJOIN("</m><m>",,FILTER(FILTER($C$2:$E$10,($B$2:$B$10=$H$1)*($A$2:$A$10=G4)),LEFT($C$1:$E$1,4)="Data"))&"</m></k>","//m")))
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: why not `Text 6 - Text 5 - Text 6`? Do we depend on the sort order implicitly?

Comment: Yes, it has to be by row order and from left to the right. Basically it should be C4 - E4 - C5 - E5 ...etc. But if E4 is the same like C5 I don't want have duplicity. .

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions for uniqueness?

Comment: Each row has unique values in the column C an E. And these are filtered by ID and date. They should by in specific order as mention above.

Comment: So why isn't the expected result "text5 - text6"? Why is "text5" to be returned a second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

[image]

Formula in `H4`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,INDEX(FILTER(C$2:E$7,(A$2:A$7=G4)*(B$2:B$7=H$1),""),SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$7,G4,B$2:B$7,H$1)),{1,3}),"'")&"</s></t>","//s[following::*[1]!=.]"))
```

Comment: I apologize for very late answer as I was very busy and this is just my hobby. But anyway I tried that and it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.